# Inequality for general polynomials.

Tags: inequality, polynomials

This may be a bit too general for anyone to give much, but nonetheless, I'd like to see if anyone has any insight.

What conditions would be necessary for the following to hold:

$$(a_1x+a_2x^2+\dots+a_n x^n)^2\geq(b_1x+b_2x^2+\dots+b_{n-2}x^{n-2})(c_1x+c_2x^2+\dots+c_{n+2}x^{n+2}),$$ for all $x\geq n$ where $a_n^2=b_{n-2}c_{n+2}$?

Specifically, the only known terms I have are $a_n=\frac{1}{2^n},b_{n-2}=\frac{1}{2^{n-2}},c_{n+2}=\frac{1}{2^{n+2}}$.

Expanding these terms is extremely messy, and hopefully unnecessary. Again, I am not expecting any general rules known for such an inequality, but here's to hoping.

Comment: Shouldn't that last term inside the parentheses on the left of the inequality be $a_nx^{n - 2}$?

Comment: Should've been $x^n$. Fixed, thanks.

Comment: If you fix any values for every coefficient except $b_i$, then by making $b_i$ sufficiently large we can make the inequality false for any given non-zero value of $x$ (excluding the $\le n+2$ roots of $c_1x+\dots$). So the condition is not going to be simple.